# Angular.js resolve throws Unknown provider error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I've looked at a number of related questions and answers on this subject, but none seem to fit my circumstances as I cannot get resolves to work without an error.

I'm trying to follow a tutorial to learn about Angular routes with resolve here, trying this example in-line in my existing app:  http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/17/resolve-in-angularjs-routes-explained-as-story/.

I'm getting this error, seems like it might relate to resolves and ng-view which I'm using?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Still rather new to Angular.  Using Rails in the back-end:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myFriendsHotelProvider <-
>   myFriendsHotel
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/unpr?p0=myFriendsHotelProvider%20%3C-%20myFriendsHotel
>       at http://lala.dev/assets/angular.js?body=1:79:12
>       at http://lala.dev/assets/angular.js?body=1:3539:19
>       at Object.getService [as get] (http://lala.dev/assets/angular.js?body=1:3666:39)
>       at http://lala.dev/assets/angular.js?body=1:3544:45
>       at getService (http://lala.dev/assets/angular.js?body=1:3666:39)
>       at invoke (http://lala.dev/assets/angular.js?body=1:3688:13)
>       at Object.instantiate (http://lala.dev/assets/angular.js?body=1:3709:23)
>       at http://lala.dev/assets/angular.js?body=1:6759:28
>       at link (http://lala.dev/assets/angular-route.js?body=1:907:26)
>       at nodeLinkFn (http://lala.dev/assets/angular.js?body=1:6213:13)

**app.js.coffee**

```
window.lala = angular.module "Lala", ["angularFileUpload", "ngResource", "ngAnimate", "ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap", "ui.bootstrap.setNgAnimate", "ui.sortable", 'ngTagsInput']

lala.config ['$httpProvider', ($httpProvider) ->
  authToken = $("meta[name=\"csrf-token\"]").attr("content")
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = authToken
]

lala.config ['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider
    .when("/accomodation",
      templateUrl: "/assets/templates/list.html"
      controller: "AccomodationCtrl"
      resolve: ->
        myFriendsHotel: ->
          hotelName: ->
            "My Friend's Hotel"
          roomNumber: ->
            "100"
    )
    .when("/home",
      templateUrl: "/assets/templates/home.html"
      controller: "HomePageCtrl"
    )
    .when("/tags/:tag",
      templateUrl: "/assets/templates/lists.html"
      controller: "ListsCtrl"
    )
    .when("/:filter",
      templateUrl: "/assets/templates/lists.html"
      controller: "ListsCtrl"
    )
    .when("/users/:id",
      templateUrl: "/assets/templates/profile.html"
      controller: "UsersCtrl"
    )

    .otherwise(redirectTo: '/recent')
]
```

**accomodation_controller.js.coffee**

```
lala.controller "AccomodationCtrl", ["$scope", "myFriendsHotel", ($scope, myFriendsHotel) ->
  $scope.name = "Shidhin"
  $scope.place = "Switzerland"
  $scope.hotel = myFriendsHotel.hotelName()
  $scope.roomno = myFriendsHotel.roomNumber()
]
```

**list.html.haml**

```
.row
  .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-8
    %div
      %h2 Hi, {{name}}. Welcome to {{place}}
      %div The accomodation is arranged on <strong>{{hotel}}</strong> and room number is <strong>{{roomno}}</strong>
  .col-xs-6.col-md-4
    #right-column
      great work
```

**angular.html.haml**

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Lala
    %meta{content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", name: "viewport"}/
    = favicon_link_tag "lala_favicon.ico"
    = stylesheet_link_tag "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato"
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags

    :javascript
      window.current_user_name = "#{current_user.try(:username)}" 
      window.current_user_image = "#{avatar_url(current_user) unless !current_user}"


  %body{"ng-app" => "Lala"}
    = render :partial => "shared/navbar"
    #page-content{iScroll: ""}
      .container.bordered
        .row
          .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
            .breadcrumb
              {{breadcrumb}}
        %div{"ng-view" => true}
          = yield
    #scroll-top
      %a{:href => "#"}
        back to top
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-up
```

Comment: Like dnc253 wrote, you are missing the myFriendsHotelProvider service definition. So somewhere in your code you should have the line lala.factory "myFriendsHotel", ->. Can't find it in the posted sc.

Comment: Make sure you have not declare ng-controller='AccomodationCtrl' anywhere

Comment: @bekite, he is not, this is getting injected from the resolve so it should work.

Comment: @Chandermani yes you are right. Didn't check the code properly. Was too focused on the error message.

Comment: @aressidi maybe this is causing the error: resolve: -> is no function. remove the -> after resolve

Comment: @bekite that was it!  All that hassle for something so silly.  Thanks for the look, and the help.

Answer (score -1):

Any time you get the `Unknown provider` error, it's because Angular doesn't know how the provide the dependency you are asking for. The error tells you which dependency that is:

```
Unknown provider: myFriendsHotelProvider <- myFriendsHotel
```

So, then the question is, why can't Angular inject `myFriendsHotel`? Check to see where that is defined, and make sure whatever module it is included in, is included in your app.